# Read Text File Having "\000" as One Character Python

Tags: python-3.x, ascii

I have text file as follows:

data.txt:

```
"\000\001\a"
```

I want to read this file into **list as ASCII value of character**

For example file above should look like this in the list:

```
list1 = [ 0, 1, 7] #ascii value of \a is 7.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
text = "\000\001\a"
result = []
for i in range(len(text)):
    byte_form = text[i].encode('utf-8')
    integer_form = int.from_bytes(byte_form, "big")
    result.append(integer_form)

print(result)
```

> [0, 1, 7]

1. convert it into byte form using:  encode('utf-8')
   https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-bytes-to-int-in-python/
2. convert into integer using:  int.from_bytes()
   https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-string-to-bytes/